# Extracting K characters to the left and right of a marker using Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have the following string.
In reality the size can be varied.

```
my $string = "ACCAGGGGGGCCTCCGCAG*AAGCGGTCGCCATAGTCAAAC";
```

What I want to do is to extract 10 characters to the left and right of a * marker,
resulting in :

```
  my $output = "GCCTCCGCAG*AAGCGGTCGC";
```

is there a compact way to do it in Perl?

Comment: You say "markers", so that means there can be more than one? Will they ever be within 10 characters of each other? If so, what output do you want for `AAGTAAGTAAGT*AAGT*AAGTAAGTAAGT`?

Comment: @ikegami: I mean only 1 marker. I have edited my OP. Thanks for pointing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There you go, a non regex solution:

```
my $string = "ACCAGGGGGGCCTCCGCAG*AAGCGGTCGCCATAGTCAAAC";
my $marker = '*';
my $offset_from_marker = 10;
my length = 21;
my $output = substr($string, index($string, $marker) - offset_from_marker, $length);
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick and easy way to do it using regular expressions. The two `{10}`s represent the number of characters to match on each side.

```
my ($output) = $string =~ m{(.{10}\*.{10})};
```

Comment: You probably want to make that `.{0,10}`, otherwise it will not print anything if you ever get a match where the context is shorter than ten characters on either side.

Comment: That's a good point, but I suspect that might end up *always* capturing too little context in some situations. Might be easier to just stick `'-' x 10` on each end first!

Comment: The greedy repetition operator will always match the longest possible string.

Comment: Removed solution that purpoited to work with multiple markers since 1) it didn't handle multiple markers with 20 of each other, much less withing 10 of each other, and 2) the OP has now made it clear that there is only one marker.